# dynamically populate dropdown list from table columns and filter

Tags: jquery

I have a table listing data from my database.
I need to filter the list using Jquery by populating the data from corresponding table columns.

But when filter table rows first column, from first dropdown, the second dropdown should list only data/texts from second column removing existing options & so on for third dropdown...

Please refer my fiddle:

```
[jsFiddle Link][1]
```

Any suggestions how this can be achieved...

Comment: You can rebind that dropdown after you have sorted the table.Loop through each row of second column and add values to dropdown.

Comment: i am able to unbind after i focus on first dropdown, using "$('.proj_numb_sel').unbind('focus');" and rebind at end using "$('.proj_numb_sel').bind('focus');" but this is not working .. PLease see my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Kumar/q3osaLpp/3/